# SwiftUI: Toggle in Table does not display value from model

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, tableview, toggle

I want to display a Table with Toggles in it on the Mac in Xcode 14. The following code creates the table correctly, but the toggle does not display the bool value it should display. It is always turned off.
The toggle actually toggles the value of the items. It just does not display the state. I have no idea, what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help in advance...

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DataGridViewApp: App {

    let tableViewProvider = TableViewProvider()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(viewProvider: tableViewProvider)
                .onAppear() { tableViewProvider.addElements() }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewProvider: TableViewProvider

    var body: some View {
        Table(viewProvider.tableViewDataList) {
            TableColumn("Value") { item in
                Toggle("", isOn: Binding<Bool>(
                    get: {
                        print("-\nget \(viewProvider.tableViewDataList.first(where: { $0.id == item.id })?.value ?? false)")
                        return viewProvider.tableViewDataList.first(where: { $0.id == item.id })?.value ?? false
                        //return item.value
                    },
                    set: {
                        print("set \($0)")
                        viewProvider.tableViewDataList.first(where: { $0.id == item.id })?.value = $0
                        print("after set \(viewProvider.tableViewDataList.first(where: { $0.id == item.id })?.value ?? false)")
                        //item.value = $0
                    })
                )
            }
            TableColumn("ID") { item in
                Text(String(item.id))
            }
        }
    }
}

class TableViewProvider: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tableViewDataList: [Item] = Array()

    func addElements() {
        tableViewDataList.append(Item(id: 1))
        tableViewDataList.append(Item(id: 2))
        tableViewDataList.append(Item(id: 3))
    }
}


class Item: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    var id: Int
    @Published var value: Bool = false

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Comment: ContentView is observing `TableViewProvider` and changing a value in `Item` does not notify the View to update since it's nested in an Array within your provider. One approach in you code could be adding `viewProvider.objectWillChange.send()`in your setter after `viewProvider.tableViewDataList.first(where: { $0.id == item.id })?.value = $0`. This would notify the view that something changed

Comment: That is exactly what I need here. Thank you! In the actual project, the `Item` must be a class, because it has much more functionality than in this demo example. So using a `struct`, as suggested in one answer, unfortunately does not work for me...

Comment: struct is best in this case, learn about mutating func for your additional model logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentView is observing TableViewProvider and changing a value in Item does not notify the View to update since it's nested in an Array within your provider. One approach in you code could be adding `viewProvider.objectWillChange.send()` in your setter after `viewProvider.tableViewDataList.first(where: { $0.id == item.id })?.value = $0`. This would notify the view that something changed

```
// ...
set: {
   print("set \($0)")
   viewProvider.tableViewDataList.first(where: { $0.id == item.id })?.value = $0

   viewProvider.objectWillChange.send() // Manually notify that viewProvider data has changed

   print("after set \(viewProvider.tableViewDataList.first(where: { $0.id == item.id })?.value ?? false)")
   print(viewProvider.tableViewDataList)
   //item.value = $0
   })
// ...
```

Comment: This hack will add the risk of consistency bugs that SwiftUI was designed to eliminate. One object to hold the model structs should usually be enough.

Comment: Not sure how an open Swift API Can be considered a hack. objectWillChange.send() is the manual version of @Published allowing more control over ObservableObject

Answer (score 0):

One thing missing in SwiftUI is working with indexes. I'm not crazy about the linear search (vs constant access with indexes).
Having said that, maybe a more proper flow would be:

1. Getting the index (rather than the item)
2. A `View` event (user toggle) triggering a data change in the viewProvider, causing the view to refresh

```swift
set: {
    if let index = viewProvider.tableViewDataList.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) {
        viewProvider.tableViewDataList[index].value = $0
    }
})
```

Could be worth creating a `[ModelID:Index]` map. Then you could do something like:

```swift
let index = viewProvider.indexForItem(id: <Int/String>)...

// On viewProvider's side, something like:
if let index = modelIndexMap[id] {
    tableViewDataList[index].value = ...
}
```